# Can't add data in SortedList C#

Tags: c#, collections

I have simple code, where I want to fill my `SortedList` with some data from arrays.

```
namespace Test
{
    class TestClass
    {
        public int ValueInt { get; set; }
        public char ValueChar { get; set; }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
            char[] arr2 = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

            SortedList<TestClass, char> list = new SortedList<TestClass, char>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                list.Add(new TestClass() { ValueInt = arr1[i], ValueChar = arr2[i]}, '+');
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<TestClass, char> kvp in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                "Key1 = {0}, Key2 = {1}, Value = {2}", 
                    kvp.Key.ValueInt, kvp.Key.ValueChar, kvp.Value
                    );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program throw error:

> System.InvalidOperationException (Failed to compare two elements in the array)

Program throw it at the point of second iteration of that loop:

```
list.Add(new TestClass() { ValueInt = arr1[i], ValueChar = arr2[i]}, '+');
```

**HOWEVER**,
Program works if I change `SortedList` to `Dictionary`

How can I make my Program works with the `SortedList` ?

Comment: SortedList need to know how to sort the keys and for that it needs to know how to compare the keys. Here you have TestClass as key type and there is no clear way to compare two objects of TestClass.

Comment: How are you going to sort an object? i mean it has to read your mind, you will need to implement a comparer or a class that as the capability to compare, how do yo want to sort this? by `valueInt`, or `ValueChar`

Comment: You need to write a class which implements `IComparer` interface. This class will compare two objects of TestClass and return appropriate value. You need to create an object of class and pass it to SortedList constructor. You can read more about SortedList [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: This is probably an XY problem, why are using an object as a key, when you can just use one the char or the int and store the object as the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*TestClass* should implement *IComparable*-interface.

> SortedList requires a comparer implementation to sort and
>   to perform comparisons
>   (see [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netframework-4.8#remarks))

```
class TestClass : IComparable<TestClass>
{
    public int ValueInt { get; set; }
    public char ValueChar { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(TestClass other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return 0;
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return 1;

        var valueIntComparison = ValueInt.CompareTo(other.ValueInt);
        if (valueIntComparison != 0) return valueIntComparison;

        return ValueChar.CompareTo(other.ValueChar);
    }
}
```